# MySQL Query to COPY/INSERT rows for one years worth of data

Tags: mysql

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id`SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  `code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `code`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'ABC', '2021-01-03'),
(2, 'ABC', '2020-10-02'),
(3, 'ABC', '2020-07-05'),
(4, 'ABC', '2020-04-10'),
(5, 'BAA', '2020-11-06'),
(6, 'BAA', '2020-05-25'),
(7, 'ABC', '2019-04-07'),
(8, 'ABC', '2019-07-07'),
(9, 'BAA', '2019-11-08'),
(10, 'BAA', '2019-05-20');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf151/1

I am trying to write a MySQL query to display 1 year's payments in the future for different stocks.

ABC pays 4 times a year, BAA pays 2 times a year, stocks could pay between 1-12 times a year (once, twice, quarterly, monthly)
There will only be either 0 or 1 PaymentDate Declared >= NOW()

For each stock code row

```
If there exists a row WHERE PaymentDate >= NOW() (A)
(
output above row with no changes
AND
output all rows for stock code WHERE PaymentDate is 1 year ago from above PaymentDate (A), 
with changes, Status=Estimate, PaymentDate incremented by +1 year
)

If all PaymentsDates for a stock are in the past < NOW(), output ALL rows 1 year ago from NOW() i.e. in the past
with changes, Status=Estimate, PaymentDate, increment year by 1
```

Output

```
Stock PaymentDate Status
ABC,  03/01/2021  Declared
ABC,  02/10/2021  Estimate
ABC,  05/07/2021  Estimate
ABC,  10/04/2021  Estimate
BAA,  06/11/2021  Estimate
BAA,  25/05/2021  Estimate
```

```
More Information
For each code group (ABC etc) in the input data

Select all rows where PaymentDate <= Max(PaymentDate) up to 1 year
If PaymentDate < NOW(), increment year +1 AND Status=Estimate
If PaymentDate >= NOW(), output row
```

So if a company like ABC has already Declared 1 of its 4 payments, output that payment plus the previous 3 payments (incrementing the year by 1 and status=Estimate)

For company BAA output the 2 latest payments (incrementing date by 1 year and status=Estimate)

The output is showing future payment dates based upon an exact copy of historic payment dates, and payment dates which have already been declared in the future, for a period of 1 year.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks for any help.

Colin

Comment: Hi Strawberry, my question has been closed, but I have simplified  the question and I hope that it will be reopened as it is an essential part of my website, Thanks Colin

Comment: Hi Strawberry here is the fiddle I have not added my SQL attempts, let me know if you want me to add my attempts to code, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf151/1, I have not added status to simplify again, I just need the date logic to work thanks Colin

Comment: Hi Strawberry I have added an explanation from More Information in the main call, hopefully more understandable, (A) is just a reference to text above. hopefully this makes sense thanks Colin

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I tried that yesterday and it displays You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. I am desperate to get a solution for this problem Thanks Colin

Comment: Well, I'm too busy to focus on this right now - but I'll try to address it later in comments if I have a moment, and if others haven't beaten me to it.

Comment: that would be great thx Colin

Comment: Just a thought... with reference to your 'more information' section, it seems to me that there are 7 rows that satisfy those criteria (1,2,3,4,5,6,9), but there are only six rows in your result set

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf151/2 and adapt to suit...

Comment: Hi Strawberry, fantastic thank you very much, that appears to be the solution exactly what I need !! well pleased Best regards Colin